# Diff a JSON Object in an existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

i have a problem with two JSON-objects.
I get my view through JSON, and when i update my site, i just want to display the changes, and not render the whole site again.

What I mean ist, I get an JSON-object when i first load my wegpage, something like that:

```
{
    "WindowObject": {
        "name": "test",
        "type": "container",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "childOne",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
     }
}
```

and when i press a button, i get a new JSON-object, with the updated view, for example:

```
{
    "WindowObject": {
        "name": "test",
        "type": "container",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "childOne",
                "type": "input"
            },
            {
                "name": "childTwo",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
     }
}
```

I render these informations with an AngularJS directive and that works fine. But the problem is, the whole site is rendered again with the "new" object, instead of just changing the new things.

So now i want to "integrate" or "diff" the new array in the old one, so that just the changed things get rendered again.

Some one has an idea?

Comment: Try `$.extend(oldJson, newJson)` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ - Like this, the old json is updated with the changes of the new one.

Comment: You could use d3.js inside this directive to create, update and delete DOM elements when changes occur in your Json-model. [It is explained here](http://d3js.org/#enter-exit)

Comment: This has nothing to with JSON per se. You want to "diff" a DOM tree.

Comment: @ErikWillems angular already does that when used properly ...why would you need another library for it?

Comment: Why can't you just push the new object into it's array. Instead of getting the whole collection again?

Comment: when i understand push right, then the problem is, that i want to add the changes of the new array, and delete the keys and values, which aren't in the new array. What means, that in the end, the "oldArray", is EXACT the "newArray", but without triggering the whole rendering process of AngularJS... oh man :/

Comment: The core question here is why are you rendering your view from a JSON object every time it changes? Why is that important? Why is it necessary to have a directive for this? If it is merely to save state, then you should only render from it the first time it's loaded and only write to it when changes occur. Let Angular do the composition it was designed to do for you.

Comment: Right now the webpage is like and rdp for an windows application. I get the whole window of the application as a JSON. When i press a button, so that another window opens, i get the new JSON, which i want to show. Or, i get the changes, like a new table or something. So i have to render the view again.

Comment: Can you include the HTML template this JSON is bound to?

Comment: Did you try using the extend approach mentioned in first comment? A deep extend should also do what you need. Angular has `angular.extend`   see docs

Comment: @Griessbrei Your last comment indicating that you, in essence, regenerate the JSON to represent entire application state with each action seems like a really bad design.

Comment: @MikeBrant totally agree. Seems like a nightmare to me

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [json diff github](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) for your solution. Basically, it works on DOM/Tree structure of json. It iterates/parse to all the nodes in json and then find the difference, as mentioned in comments.